# CRC-24 calculation method validation

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I am working on a BLE Beacon application and to generate the packet to be advertised I need to calculate a 24-bits CRC value out of the BLE header, source access and the payload.
In the [official specification of Bluetooth](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=457080) I found the following information that I used to generate the value[section 3.1.1 page:2737]:

The polynomial generator has the form :
 x24 + x10 + x9 + x6 + x4 + x3 + x + 1

and the  the shift register shall be preset with 0x555555.

I want to make confirm wether this is the correct specification for my use case or I am on the wrong section?